# Drawer on right side is visible in responsive view

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to develop a sidebar drawer on the right side. However, when the drawer is hidden it became visible on mobile view. I tried translateX and negative right in the sidebar. It works fine in both cases but when I do inspect elements and see in responsive view they are visible.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

add a @media query to make it suitable for mobile view

Comment: I can change the display to none as well but I want to have animation. It is perfectly working on normal use. But as you can see in the image, when i inspect element it is visible but I dont want it to be visible in that case also.

Comment: did you set overflow to its parent?

Comment: yes tried overflow hidden, no success

Comment: Solved, since it is a whole window drawer, I added a display hidden to the body tag but I also had to put the position relative to the body.  So, position relative and overflow-x hidden in body tag worked.

Comment: great then, best of luck